# update date full column on changing only one datafield

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

i have 2 table Table A and B

Table A data

---

```
Enquiry_Id  Ckeck_In    check_Out   Place
129         2013-09-20  2013-09-23  Delhi
130         2013-08-09  2013-08-10  Agra
130         2013-08-10  2013-08-12  Punjab
130         2013-08-12  2013-08-13  Haryana
```

Table B Data

```
 Enquiry_Id        Arrives_On   Arrives_Details      
  129              2013-09-20       NA            
  130              2013-08-09       NA
```

I want when i update my table B Arrives_on Date 2013-08-09 to 2012-08-14 where enquiry_Id is 130 then my table A data will be automatically change check_In and Check_Out date. Like

```
 Enquiry_Id Ckeck_In    check_Out   Place
129         2013-09-20  2013-09-23  Delhi
130         2013-08-14  2013-08-15  Agra
130         2013-08-15  2013-08-17  Punjab
130         2013-08-17  2013-08-18  Haryana
```

Comment: -have you tried anything ?

Comment: what will happen to existing record in t able, i cannot see enq id 130 and date 09/08/2013 in o/p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger on TableB where you calculate difference between previous (`DELETED`) and updated (`INSERTED`) value and add that difference to your `TableA` columns.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgTableBUpdate ON TableB
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE a
        SET a.Ckeck_In = DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD,d.Arrives_On, i.Arrives_On), a.Ckeck_In)
       ,a.Check_Out = DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD,d.Arrives_On, i.Arrives_On), a.check_Out)
    FROM INSERTED i
    INNER JOIN DELETED d ON i.Enquiry_Id = d.Enquiry_Id
    INNER JOIN dbo.TableA a ON i.Enquiry_Id = a.Enquiry_Id AND d.Enquiry_Id = a.Enquiry_Id

END
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afcbb/4)**

Comment: if one more table table C fields are enquiry_Id and Check_In, in this table check_in also reflect like table A where enuiry_ID = 130 then how can we manage 3 tables

Comment: @Shiv You can add another UPDATE statement below for other table

Answer (score 0):

You can create an update trigger in the database on table B

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON [dbo].[B] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    declare @ArrivesOn datetime;
    declare @id int;

    SELECT @id =i.Enquiry_Id, @ArrivesOn=Arrives_On from inserted i;   

      -- perform update.insert here  like
      -- Insert into A(Enquiry_Id,NewDate) values(@id ,@ArrivesOn)

GO
```

Comment: This is very wrong way of using triggers. You should never assign variables read from `inserted` table, but use the `inserted` table directly. `Inserted` can contain multiple rows when more records are updated with single command and this way trigger will only work on single record.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use trigger for this.

```
USE [YOUR_DATABASE]
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateCheckInCheckOutDates] ON [dbo].[Table_B]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Before_Date date, @After_Date date, @Date_Diff smallint, @Id int
  SET @Date_Diff = 0

  SELECT @Id = D.Enquiry_Id, @Before_Date = D.Arrives_On FROM DELETED D
  SELECT @After_Date = I.Arrives_On FROM INSERTED I

  IF UPDATE(Arrives_On)
  BEGIN 
    SET @Date_Diff = DATEDIFF(day, @Before_Date, @After_Date)
    IF(@Date_Diff) <> 0)
    BEGIN
      UPDATE Table_A SET Check_In = @After_Date,
             Check_Out = DATEADD(DD, @Date_Diff, @After_Date)
             WHERE Enquiry_Id = @Id
    END
  END
END
```